# Search xml file and fill HTML table with result in php

Tags: php, html, xml

Hello Every body i have a xml file which i am showing in html table by using simplexml library. i want to search the file for the records by using elements values. 
Here the xml file content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StudentsList>
<Student>
<student_id email="test@yahoo.com">18700</student_id>
<firstName>Jhon</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<address>Dragon Vally china</address>
</Student>
<Student>
<student_id email="LeeSin@gmail.com">18701</student_id>
<firstName>Lee</firstName>
<lastName>Sin</lastName>
<address>League Of Legend UK</address>
</Student>
</StuedntsList>
```

i am using php right now i am able to find the specified student for the searched value of firstname or lastname. But i have no clue how to reset the current html table with all records and fill the result of the searched value.
i am using following php code for searching.

```
$firstName = "Lee";
$searched_stu_fName = $xml->xpath("//StudentsList/Student/firstName[contains(text(),'$firstName')]/parent::*");
if(count($searched_stu_fName) > 0) {
    print_r ($searched_stu_fName);
    echo "found Student";

}
```

print statement give the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [student_id] => 18701 [firstName] => Lee [lastName] => Sin [address] => League Of Legend UK ) )
```

Now i want to reload the html table with this record only right now i am having all the students in xml file showing there.

i just need some ideas or guidance thanks for any suggestions in advance and sorry for my bad english.
in php i am loading file by using these line of codes

```
$file = file_get_contents('student.xml');

$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);
```

in html i am showing in a table

```
<table>
<?php foreach($xml->Student as $student) :?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $student->student_id.'('.$student->student_id['email'].')'; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->firstName; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->lastName; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->address; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: could you show the code where you display all the students?

Comment: yes sure just one sec.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, when you print all the students it's a list of objects where one property is a student. When you just want to print one student with the filter it's an array of student objects.

That's why the loop could look like this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach($searched_stu_fName as $student) :?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php echo $student->student_id.'('.$student->student_id['email'].')'; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->firstName; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->lastName; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $student->address; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: ok i got it but i redraw or refresh the table in which i am showing all the records.

Comment: ajax or page refresh?